# Missing “Deploy”-Button Visual Studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio, sharepoint, visual-studio-2012, deployment, sharepoint-2013

Yesterday I have installed Visual Studio 2012 Premium on my SharePoint 2013 Development Machine. I also installed the Office Developer Tools to get the SP2013 Project templates.

Opening my SP 2010 Solution File and converting to 2013 was successful.

**My problem**: There is no "Deploy"-Button in the Project-Context-Menu anymore. Everything is there: Build, Rebuild, Retract etc.

But no **Deploy**.

[Asked this in the SharePoint Forum too](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/82878/missing-deploy-button-visual-studio-2012)

Comment: Have you put valid site url in project's site url property?

Comment: Is there a deploy option if you right-click the solution?

Comment: I have put a valid Url in the properties window. But no Deploy option on project right click. On Solution it exists but I do not want to deploy the whole solution!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had the same problem.

I started by creating some solutions folders, and placing my SharePoint project in those. After moving a project from root --> frontend\ , the deploy menu item, in the context menu of the project disappeared.

I solved this, I had to move the SharePoint project to the root-folder of the solution, and the deployment feature re-appeared in the project context menu.

Comment: Checked this. This is a very bad bug I think, but in VS 2013 everything is working correctly :P

Comment: The scenario played out in VS 2013... :(

Comment: In VS 2013 for me its working fine only in 2012 the deploy button is not visible. Never the less, MS **must** fix this!

Comment: It seems like the "Deploy Selection" option still works, but you'll have to select two or more items for it to appear in the context menu. Selecting the project plus the containing folder oddly does the trick...