# "Deploy" option missing visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012, sharepoint-2013, wsp

I have recently migrated a sharepoint project from a vs 2010 solution to a vs 2012 solution. Previously, I have used the "deploy solution" option found under the build menu or simply by right clicking the solution level itself to obtain the needed wsp. However, I can no longer find this option. Has it been removed? Has it been renamed? Please advise.

Comment: There should be "Deploy" option when you right click on project. If it is missing maybe project migration went wrong or maybe you do not have office tools for visual studio 2012.  http://aka.ms/OfficeDevToolsForVS2012. When you go to project properties do you see "Site Url" property?

Comment: @Yevgeniy.Chernobrivets The migration report states that "Solution migrated successfully." Where might I find the "Site URL" property? I do not see it under properties -> Application. If it helps, I DO get a successful build as well.

Comment: It should be in project properties. Right click on project than "Properties".

Comment: Probably the same issue and solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/20188662/1375553

Comment: I tried the above solution with no luck. I do not even have a "Deploy" option at the solution level. Funny thing is, I believe I saw the Deploy option on my initial migration.

Comment: Is there an alternative mean to creating the wsp? Through powershell perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

Well i dont have an issue when i create a Visual WebPart from scratch.  I know that previous WebParts from 2007, had issue on the migration to 2013.  If i were you make sure that Project/Solution created is not basically a Web Site/Page project instead of an App for SharePoint Solution.

If its not an Apps for SharePoint solution, then you will have to do the fun of creating it all from scratch, at least copying the code fragments over.  The folder structure is not the same from 2007, and im sure they changed it again from 2010.